# HTML/CSS: the width of the parent is dependent on the child

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry, my english is not good :)

When resize the width of the window. How width of `dm2` is dependent on the `to-n` sorted column?

`dm1`,`dm2` is no fixed width in css.

I tried to use `text-align` for `dm1`. `display: inline` for `dm2`. It works fine, but I found it at fault. I do not know no other way handle it?

Demo Here: https://jsfiddle.net/bindo1995/m4vajbqw/2/

Default

[image]

Use `text-align` for `dm1`, `display:inline;` for `dm2`

[image]

How ?

[image]

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: You are expected to append your code directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using float or display: inline-block; to-n blocks will always try to fit horizontally on one row when there is enough space for each block and when there is no space for a block it will be on the second row and there will be gap in dm2. If you want them to be 3 on first row and 2 on the second and to fit 100% in dm2 you have to make 2 rows of to-n blocks.